# Display message only once if an exception occur in a function and the function being used multiple time:

Tags: python-3.x, function, exception

I have defined a simple function and there I am raising an exception if anything unusual happens. and same function is being called multiple time, so if that exception occurs, then same message is being displayed multiple time, wherever, that function has been called, so is it possible to log this exception only once, below is the error which is coming:

```
def divide(x, y):
    """Divide Function"""
    try:
        result = x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Tried to divide by zero")
    else:
        return result
def multiply(x, y):
    """Multiply Function"""
    try:
        z = divide(x, y)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        return x * y
num_1 = 10
num_2 = 0
mul_result = multiply(num_1, num_2)
```

Below is the error which is coming:

```
Tried to divide by zero
Tried to divide by zero
```

I don't want to do sys.exit() or raise the exception as there are other modules which needs to run fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you don't want the exceptions to halt the execution of your program, but you only want an exception message printed once and only once, a quick and dirty way to do this is:

```
exception_logged = False

def divide(x, y):
    """Divide Function"""
    try:
        result = x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        if not exception_logged:
            print("Tried to divide by zero")
            exception_logged = True
    else:
        return result
    def multiply(x, y):
    """Multiply Function"""
    try:
        z = divide(x, y)
    except Exception as e:
        if not exception_logged:
            print(e)
            exception_logged = True
    else: # <--- It is strange to have an else without an if
        return x * y
num_1 = 10
num_2 = 0
mul_result = multiply(num_1, num_2)
```

Comment: try has 4 blocks, try, except, else and finalyy so as I am a new learner so trying to use whatever I can. You solution fine if there are 2 function, but suppose there are mutiple modules in the file and each module has separate dependency. How can we do that. Kindly suggest!